# facing quite strange issue in popup closing in react. method is getting called but popup is not closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks

I have created one component. in which I have a button in which once you click popup will be displayed.
data for that `popup` is put in another component. below is the popup.

[image]

the problem is once I am clicking on the cross`(x)` button at corner my popuup is not getting closed.

below is the code to launch popup.

```
const [statusUpdateFlag, setStatusUpdateFlag] = useState(false);
     <td>
                    <button type="button" onClick={(event) => handleStatusUpdateClick(event)}>
                     click
                    {statusUpdateFlag && (
                      <StatusUpdate
                                certificate={props.certificate}
                                handleStatusUpdateClick={handleStatusUpdateClick}
                                closePopUp={closePopUp}
                            />
                    )}       
                    </button>
          </td>
```

once user click on the `button` , `statusUpdateFlag` will be true popup will be launched.

```
 const handleStatusUpdateClick = async (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setStatusUpdateFlag(true);
 }
```

now on the `close` button I have just made  `setStatusUpdateFlag(false);` . even this method is getting called. still popup is not closing.

```
const closePopUp = (event: any) => {
        alert("closepopup called");
        event.preventDefault();
        setStatusUpdateFlag(false);
    };
```

once I click `X` method is getting called but `popup` is not closing.
[image]

below is code for `X` button,

```
<button
  className={styles.closeicon}
  onClick={(event) => props.closePopUp(event)}
>
  x
</button>
```

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Can you add a minimal prototype using something like codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the Popup component as children of your button, so when you click on popup close, a trigger for parent button click is also triggered so popup visible state is again set true.

```
const [statusUpdateFlag, setStatusUpdateFlag] = useState(false);
<td>
    <button type="button" onClick={(event) => handleStatusUpdateClick(event)}>
        click
        {/* Issue is here */}
        {statusUpdateFlag && (
            <StatusUpdate
                certificate={props.certificate}
                handleStatusUpdateClick={handleStatusUpdateClick}
                closePopUp={closePopUp}
            />
        )}
    </button>
</td>;
```

You should bring out the `StatusUpdate` component outside button and in my opinion for UI, outside the whole table component if possible. That should fix the issue.

Comment: you know Shivam, I spent arouind 10hrs to figure out this issue still could not resolve. you resolved in just 10 mins. thank you so much Man.

Comment: That's just the benefit of another point of view, I am happy I could help 